# What is the difference between the "Guest" and the "Not logged in" customer groups in Magento?

Tags: magento

What is the difference between the following customer groups in Magento:

```
Guest
```

v

```
Not Logged In
```

To me these are both the same but when are each used?  I believe this to be a source of a bug I am investigating as they both use different customer group id's 0 and 1 respectively.

Comment: Additionally, the NOT LOGGED IN customers will have customer_id of NULL in the sales_flat_order table.

Answer (score 2):

Customer groups are simply a way of grouping customers that register, or are not logged in (in the case of the NOT LOGGED IN group only) on the store for things like assigning a tax band, and applying promotions.

The NOT LOGGED IN group is the only one which can apply to guests and cannot be edited or deleted.  The names of all other groups is irrelevant, it's how you use that group when for instance creating tax rules, so if you have a group named Guest that is a custom group which has been created and can only apply to logged in customers (the only other default group created by Magento itself is called General).

See here for more info:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/welcome_to_the_magento_user_s_guide/chapter_6#creating_customer_groups

Comment: are you saying that customers who are not logged in, always are assigned to the NOT LOGGED IN group, and cannot be assigned to other groups?

Comment: You can only assign registered customers with an account to a group, so yes the only option for customers who are not logged in is the NOT LOGGED IN group.

Comment: Thanks. This means that you cannot differentiate users over tax groups, like EU tax exemption for foreign EU customers with VAT number.